# Android FragmentPagerAdapter with same fragment class

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentpageradapter, android-tablayout

I'm making a score keeping app using tabs, tablayout, fragments, and a FragmentPagerAdapter. The app runs fine, but I can't figure out how I can access the fragments. After doing some work in the fragment, I want to access the fragment to update its score. How can I access the current fragment?

Edit - my main problem is finding the position. I can use tabLayout.getSelectedTabPosition() to get the correct position if I clicked on the tab, but if I swipe between tabs, viewpager handles it differently and I don't know how to find the position from that.

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private int numTabs;

    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int tabs) {
        super(fm);
        numTabs = tabs;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return makeScoreFrag(1, "Team 1");
            case 1:
                return makeScoreFrag(2, "Team 2");
            case 2:
                return makeScoreFrag(3, "Team 3");
            case 3:
                return makeScoreFrag(4, "Team 4");
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return numTabs;
    }

    private ScoreFragment makeScoreFrag(int num, String title){
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt("score", 0);
        bundle.putInt("number", num);
        bundle.putString("title", title);
        ScoreFragment frag = new ScoreFragment();
        frag.setArguments(bundle);
        return frag;
    }
}
```

Comment: You may explore if adding OnPageChangeListener for the ViewPager to keep track of the selected page could address your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can Override instantiateItem method in FragmentPagerAdapter

```
ScoreFragment[] fragments = new ScoreFragment[numTabs];
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {
    fragments[position] = (ScoreFragment) super.instantiateItem(container, position);
   return fragments[position];
}
```

Then current fragment is:

```
ScoreFragment curFragment = fragments[curTab];
```